# Where should I place additional code in override fun onDestroy() { ... }?

Tags: android

In many Android Studio projects, I should place additional code in `override fun onDestroy() { }`  to release resources.

Should I place these codes before `super.onDestroy()` or after `super.onDestroy()` ?

In my mind, both the Code A and Code B I have met, which one is correct between Code A and Code B?

**Code A**

```
class ServiceRecord: Service() {

    private var job: Job? = null  

    override fun onDestroy() {       
        job?.cancel()
        super.onDestroy()
    }  
   
    ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
class ServiceRecord: Service() {

    private var job: Job? = null  

    override fun onDestroy() {              
        super.onDestroy()
        job?.cancel()
    }  
   
    ...
}
```